# Omitting the datatype (e.g. "unsigned" instead of "unsigned int")

Tags: c++, c, types

I know that if the data type declaration is omitted in C/C++ code in such way: `unsigned test=5;`, the compiler automatically makes this variable an int (an unsigned int in this case). I've heard that it's a C standard and it will work in all compilers.

**But** I've also heard that doing this is considered a bad practice.

What do you think? Should I really type `unsigned int` instead of just `unsigned`?

Are `short`, `long` and `long long` also datatypes?

Comment: Just saw it being used and came here to ask the exact same thing. Don't like it, but there it is.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`unsigned` **is a data type**! And it happens to alias to `unsigned int`.

When you’re writing `unsigned x;` you are *not* omitting any data type.

This is completely different from “default `int`” which exists in C (but not in C++!) where you really omit the type on a declaration and C automatically infers that type to be `int`.

As for style, I personally prefer to be explicit and thus to write `unsigned int`. On the other hand, I’m currently involved in a library where it’s convention to just write `unsigned`, so I do that instead.

Comment: +1:  Right.  `unsigned` is really just an alias for `unsigned int`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are `short`, `long` & `long long` datatypes then?

Comment: @rhino:  Yes.  Each you mentioned is a distinct datatype

Comment: In C99 `unsigned` *is* an alias for `unsigned int` in the same way as C++ (section 6.7.2).

Comment: +1 for preferring explicit declarations yet deferring to coding standards.

Answer (score 10):

I would even take it one step further and use [stdint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h)'s uint32_t type.
It might be a matter of taste, but I prefer to know what primitive I'm using over some ancient consideration of optimising per platform.

Comment: But `std::uint32_t` is **not** a "primitive". It's an optional `typedef` to a type that must have exactly 32 bits and may or may not be a primitive.

Answer (score 5):

As @Konrad Rudolph says, `unsigned` *is* a datatype.  It's really just an alias for `unsigned int`.

As to the question of using `unsigned` being bad practice?  I would say no, there is nothing wrong with using `unsigned` as a datatype specifier.  Professionals won't be thrown by this, and any coding standard that says you have to use `unsigned int` is needlessly draconian, in my view.

Answer (score 1):

*Gratuitous verbosity considered harmful.* I would never write `unsigned int` or `long int` or `signed` anything (except `char` or bitfields) because it increases clutter and decreases the amount of meaningful code you can fit in 80 columns. (Or more likely, encourages people to write code that does not fit in 80 columns...)

Comment: I find that people breaking up lines simply so they fit into an 80 character limit can hurt readability.  Verbosity has its place.  What level of verbosity someone accepts is up to their taste.  I tend to err on the side of verbosity and explicitness, myself.

Comment: I find breaking up lines hurts readability too, but not more than horizontal scrolling. Thus the best is to avoid filling up space with meaningless characters (and avoid both at the same time).

Comment: "I would never write `unsigned int`" me neither! ..."or `signed`" this one I'm not sure about; I've tended to prefer writing `signed` than `int`, for symmetry with `unsigned`... but there is indeed a point that `int` is better due to its brevity.