# Why does adding two float numbers give an integer in C++?

Tags: c++, floating-point, formatting, integer, iostream

I tried to calculate the sum of two floats `6.5` and `7.5` in C++. I expected the result to be a float with decimals like `14.000000`. But it gave an answer `14`, and integer without decimals.

Can someone explain what is happening?

```
#include <iostream.h>
int main ()
{     
  float number1, number2;
  sum,average;
   cout<<"Enter 2 numbers";
   cout<<"number1=";
   cin>>number1;
   cout<<"number2=";
  cin>>"number2;
  sum = numberl+number2;
  average=sum/2;
  cout << "sum=" <<sum ;
   cout << "Average = " << average;
  return 0;
 }
```

The output is:

```
Enter 2 numbers: 6.5 7.5
Sum=14
Average=7
```

Comment: Try `#include <iomanip>  /* ... */ std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << your_value << '\n';`

Comment: You need to provide details, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: also choose either C or C++ (not both) and post your code here

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout

Comment: It looks like you are using an ancient compiler. `iostream.h` was removed decades ago. In such a case it's important to know which compiler you are using. Is this the good old Turbo C++ from 1996? Such old compilers behave very differently as "modern" compilers from after 1998.

Comment: When you enter program text into a Stack Overflow question or answer, copy and paste the **exact** code. Do not retype it. The code in the question has at least three problems that look like retyping errors: `sum,average;` is missing a keyword. `cin>>"number;` has a quote mark it should not. And `sum = numberl+number2;` has an `l` instead of a `1`. Mistakes like this impede people from reproducing your problem or understanding your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> float number1, number2;
>   sum,average;
> ```

That's strange moment. Seems like second line is declaration of two variables with type `int`. It actually shouldn't work, but according to your text seems like it does. Also you are using some very old compiler.

The fix is simple: either add `float`:

```
float number1, number2;
float sum, average;
```

or replace semicolon by comma:

```
float number1, number2, sum, average;
```

Also I'd like to say that it's better to use `double` then `float`.

Comment: Indeed, old C (and C++?) compilers assumed `int` when the type was left out. Nice observation... ;-)

Comment: @Scheff, I know about default int, but I thought it worked only for functions arguments and return type. Did it really worked so that any word in code like `qqq;` would declare a new integer variable? Actually I remembered that I've played with declaring a function pointer starting from `(*`... Interesting. And it was never a part of C++ as I know, only for C.

Comment: Now, where you ask, I became uncertain. Actually, I never relied on this neither in C nor in C++. I found this answer to [SO: Omitting the datatype (e.g. “unsigned” instead of “unsigned int”)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4315841/7478597), which mentions the default `int` as well.

Comment: @Scheff, I played with it when was writing a program that should compile both in C and Pascal. For C `(*` was declaring a pointer and for pascal it was beginning of the comment. And it definitely was placed in the very beginning of the file.

Comment: Found an even better answer: [SO: Why does/did C allow implicit function and typeless variable declarations?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11835427/7478597)

Comment: As I recall, declarations could be typeless but not completely declaration-keyword-less. You had to have `static` or `extern` or something; the compiler would not just recognize `foo;` as a declaration.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this code doesn't compile nor on old compilers nor on new ones, since there is an invalid double quote in this line:

```
cin>>"number2;
```

Since there are typos, it is not clear if this is the original code, but this line:

```
sum,average;
```

should lead to a compilation error since you use undefined variables.  The K&>R grammar for old C compilers allowed a function to be declared without type, which meant it was `int`.  But that was for functions only. Variables had to have at least one type specifier.

Assuming that there was a typo and that the last character of the previous line was a `,` and not a `;` the variables would be `float`, which is your expectation.

Finally,  with the typos corrected, it appears that it is **only a formatting issue**.  The default formating for a floating point in C++ is to use an integer format if the value has no meaningful decimals.

You can force a decimal representation:

- with `cout<<showpoint<<sum<<endl;`
- with `cout<<fixed<<sum<<endl;`.
- or wwith [`scientific`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) presentation, but it would then be displayed as 1.4e+01

Answer (score 0):

The output “14” is not a floating-point number or an integer type. It is character text. It does not indicate the value used with `cout << sum` had any particular type.

The reason that adding 6.5 and 7.5 gave an integer result is because the mathematical result is 14, and 14 is an integer. Floating-point types are capable of representing integers. When you output this value with `cout << sum`, the default formatting produces the text “14”.

To instruct the stream to show a decimal point and trailing zeros for floating-point outputs, insert `cout.setf(ios_base::showpoint);` into your code.